# Interpretation script for Yolo's region based output to openvino

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, yolo, openvino

Hello I am new to OPENCV/CVAT, I use openvino to run auto annotation, I want to use YoloV3 for this mission.

I need to convert Yolo model to OpenVINO format for opencv/cvat/auto_annotation.
 https://github.com/opencv/cvat/tree/develop/cvat/apps/auto_annotation.

To annotate a task with a custom model I need to prepare 4 files:

1. Model config (*.xml) - a text file with network configuration.
2. Model weights (*.bin) - a binary file with trained weights.
3. Label map (*.json) - a simple json file with label_map dictionary
   like object with string values for label numbers.
4. Interpretation script (*.py) - a file used to convert net output
   layer to a predefined structure which can be processed by CVAT. This
   code will be run inside a restricted python's environment, but it's
   possible to use some builtin functions like str, int, float, max,
   min, range.

I converted Yolo model to OpenVINO format and created xml and bin files. I write the mapping lson file.
Now I need to write interpretation python script for Yolo's region based output. How can I do that?
Is there an interrupt file from tensorflow models to openvino?

Answer (score 1):

Recommend you to start with Yolo V3 C++ or Python sample.

For C++:

https://github.com/opencv/open_model_zoo/tree/master/demos/object_detection_demo_yolov3_async

For python sample:

https://github.com/opencv/open_model_zoo/tree/master/demos/python_demos/object_detection_demo_yolov3_async

Similar discussion can be found in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/computer-vision/topic/816875

Answer (score 0):

This is now bundled with CVAT. The interpret script and json file can be found in the repo here: https://github.com/opencv/cvat/tree/develop/utils/open_model_zoo/yolov3